# Spring Security antMatcher rule based on custom headers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, http-headers

Within the Spring framework I'm currently trying to use custom headers rather than urls to distinguish some endpoints. At the moment, I can't seem to see how I would allow a particular URL with a custom header, but deny another within Spring Security. My Security config currently has an antMatcher which looks like this:

```
.antMatchers( HttpMethod.POST, "/api/website-user" ).permitAll()
```

However I have a few other 'POST' methods which are also protected - for this particular endpoint I only want it to be identified and excluded via the headers sent.

How do you got about telling Spring security that this URL should get passed through unauthenticated

```
 @PostMapping( headers = "X-Operation-Name=forgot-password" )
   public WebsiteUser forgotPassword( @Valid PasswordResetRequestModel passwordReset )
```

but this one for example does not (and relies on an authenticated user)?

```
@PostMapping( headers = "X-Operation-Name=resend-verification" )
   public WebsiteUser resendVerification( Principal principal )
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always implement a `RequestMatcher` to define your customised HTTP request matching logic. If a matcher return true for a HTTP request , it will permit that request to access :

```
public MyRequestMatcher implements RequestMatcher {

    boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request){
         //Define the matching logic here....
         if(request.getHeader("xxx") != null &&
            request.getHeader("xxx").equals("yyyy"){
             return true;
         }
         //blablablab
    }
}
```

And to configure to use this matcher :

```
 httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(new MyRequestMatcher()).permitAll();
```

Spring Security also provide some common `RequestMatcher` such as `RequestHeaderRequestMatcher` and `AndRequestMatcher` , which should be suitable for your needs:

```
//This matches if the request has X-Operation-Name header and its value is forgot-password
RequestHeaderRequestMatcher headerMatcher = new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("X-Operation-Name","forgot-password" );

// This matches if the request is POST to the /api/website-user
AntPathRequestMatcher antRequestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/website-user", HttpMethod.POST)

// This matches if both of the above matches matches 
AndRequestMatcher andMatcher = new AndRequestMatcher(headerMatcher,antRequestMatcher );

httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(andMatcher).permitAll();
```